# How to calculate DH parameters for Higher Pair?

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, design, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

I am trying to build a robot which is having Bevel Gears connecting two links. I want to calculate DH parameters, but i am stuck with this bevel gear as when the joint rotates both angle and displacement are being changed.

Comment: Could you add a diagram of the links?

Answer (score 1):

When you think about the mechanism the gears are offset, but the joint itself has an axis. You should use that axis which may not be overlapping/coincident  with the link attached to the bevel gear.

I found a few tutorials that you may find useful:

- https://blog.robotiq.com/how-to-calculate-a-robots-forward-kinematics-in-5-easy-steps
- https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-find-denavit-hartenberg-parameter-tables/
- [https://users.cs.duke.edu/~brd/Teaching/Bio/asmb/current/Papers/chap3-forward-kinematics.pdf](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Ebrd/Teaching/Bio/asmb/current/Papers/chap3-forward-kinematics.pdf)